# Web Share Target API does not work on Android 9 with OS version

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, android-manifest, progressive-web-apps

Why Web Share Target API does not work with below `manifest.json` targeting Android 9 OS version?

```
{
    "short_name": "OS",
    "name": "OS",
    "share_target": {
      "action": "/view/home/stream",
      "params": {
        "title": "title",
        "text": "text",
        "url": "/"
      }
    },
    "icons": [
      {
        "src": "icons/icon-72x72.png",
        "sizes": "72x72",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "src": "icons/icon-96x96.png",
        "sizes": "96x96",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "src": "icons/icon-144x144.png",
        "sizes": "144x144",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "src": "icons/icon-192x192.png",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "src": "icons/icon-256x256.png",
        "sizes": "256x256",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "src": "icons/icon-384x384.png",
        "sizes": "384x384",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "src": "icons/icon-512x512.png",
        "sizes": "512x512",
        "type": "image/png"
      }
    ],
    "start_url": "/",
    "display": "standalone",
    "theme_color": "#33D5AC",
    "background_color": "#ffffff",
    "orientation": "portrait-primary"
  }
```

Comment: "Does not work"?

Comment: If you have some errors you are seeing could add, perhaps someone could help.

Comment: "method": "GET" is not mentioned as part of the "share_target" action , if its a post action try Something like this     "method": "POST",
    "enctype": "multipart/form-data".

Comment: There is No Scope Mentioned as part of the manifest , Kindly Mention "scope": "/view/" and The scope defines the set of URLs that the browser considers to be within your app, and is used to decide when the user has left the app. The scope controls the URL structure that encompasses all the entry and exit points in your web app. Your start_url must reside within the scope. source : https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest

Answer (score 0):

I see a few things that could be the source of your problem.
Firstly I think you need to add a method to your share_target property. So

```
"method": "GET"
```

Also the url in this property is really more like a mapping of what query parameter we want to accept the value of the url so have a `/` wont be acceptable you may want to instead have

```
"url": "url"
```

and this will map to the url property on the query parameter, in the end you want something more along the lines of this

```
   {
    "short_name": "OS",
    "name": "OS",
    "share_target": {
      "action": "/view/home/stream",
      "method": "GET",
      "params": {
        "title": "title",
        "text": "text",
        "url": "url"
      }
    },
    "icons": [
      {
        "src": "icons/icon-72x72.png",
        "sizes": "72x72",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "src": "icons/icon-96x96.png",
        "sizes": "96x96",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "src": "icons/icon-144x144.png",
        "sizes": "144x144",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "src": "icons/icon-192x192.png",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "src": "icons/icon-256x256.png",
        "sizes": "256x256",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "src": "icons/icon-384x384.png",
        "sizes": "384x384",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "src": "icons/icon-512x512.png",
        "sizes": "512x512",
        "type": "image/png"
      }
    ],
    "start_url": "/",
    "display": "standalone",
    "theme_color": "#33D5AC",
    "background_color": "#ffffff",
    "orientation": "portrait-primary"
  }
```

see [this link](https://web.dev/web-share-target/) for more info